# UICollectionViewCell zero spacing not working

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uikit

I did create a custom calendar based on `UICollectionView`.

One `UICollectionViewCell` - one date in the calendar. I want to delete spacing between cells.
`CollectionView` layout settings -

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: (collectionView.frame.width / 7), height: collectionView.frame.width / 7)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0.0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0.0
}
```

[image]

In different screen sizes, unless iPhone X, we will see the spacing between cells.

[image]

How to fix it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution - 
 1. Delete from storyboard leading and trailing constraints from calendar view.
 2. Set center horizontally constraint
 3. Set width constraint to calendar view.
 4. Create @IBOutlet calendarWidthConstraint
 5. In viewDidLoad -

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
let width = self.view.frame.width
let cellSize = CGFloat(width / 7).rounded()
let newWidth = cellSize * 7
layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: cellSize, height: cellSize)
calendarWidth.constant = newWidth
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
```

Comment: So basically you did exactly what I said in my answer, and then you give yourself the check mark.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have a rounding error. You are saying

```
collectionView.frame.width / 7
```

An iPhone 11 is 414 points wide. 414 / 7 is 59.14285714. There is no way to portray a fractional point on the screen, so now what? We round down, and now there is an extra pixel space between cells.

Comment: So, how I can fix that? Can you help me, please?

Comment: Well, obviously you would have to provide integer values for the cell widths — values that add to exactly the screen width, even if they are not the _same_ value for _every_ cell. However, it's hard for me to get behind the whole question, because I think using a collection view with a flow layout to make a grid is silly.

Comment: Hello! I found a solution. Check my answer

Answer (score 1):

This is occurring because of the rounding-off of decimal places when your providing `collectionView.frame.width / 7` just as matt has said in his answer. Seems you are trying to avoid this because you don't want users to see that bit of gap between the cells. Mostly you would only see this on a simulator an not on a real device due to the pixel density. You can overcome this fault either by replacing the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` with a `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout` which is available only from `iOS 12`. A simple fix would be to create a custom background view for the cell that extends the `UICollectionViewCell` by just 1 pixel. Here is an example of how I tried to achieve this:

```swift
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.backgroundColor = .purple
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = .brown
    cell.addSubview(view) // Comment this line and you can see the gap
    view.frame = cell.bounds
    view.frame.size = CGSize(width: view.frame.size.width + 1, height: view.frame.size.height + 1)
    return cell
}
```

This was a nice little hack I found a while back. Hope this helps you too.

Comment: Hello! I found a solution. Check my answer